# how to get message box to pop up on my canvas widget (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

I'm trying to get my message box to pop up on top of my canvas but when I use:

```
top = Toplevel(root)
messagebox.showinfo("Title", "message", parent=top)
```

it opens another window where the message box pops up, how can i get the message box to pop up on my canvas

Comment: What is the `Toplevel()` here for? remove the `Toplevel()` and try again. Aside from that if that does not work please read the following and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What do you mean by "on" here? Do you want it to be a floating window that hovers above the canvas, or more like something that is part of the canvas window? Also you mention a canvas but your code doesn't show a canvas.